# Como enviar datos recibidos con Scanner (introducidos desde teclado) a constructor?

Tags: java

La tarea que tengo consiste en:

1. Crear 3 clases,la primera sera superclase y tendra 5 atributos que uno elija,estos los ingresara desde teclado utilizando un
   constructor y los mostrara.
2. En la segunda clase tendrá 4 atributos privados, 3 métodos dos serán privados y un publico que invoque a los miembros privados y
       los muestre .Ademas  esta clase tendrá acceso al  constructor de la
       superclase.
3. La tercera clase tendrá un método y un constructor que usted va a sobrecargar las veces que desee esos métodos serán públicos o
       privados .
4. La cuarta clase tendrá el método principal donde invocara a las anteriores.

Al hacer el codigo no se porque me marca error la parte en la cual instancio en la clase principal el objeto para invocar el constructor y que este imprima los datos introducidos por el teclado.

esto es lo que he podido hacer del codigo:

Clase "claseprincipal":

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class claseprincipal{

    //tendrá el método principal la cual tendrá su nombre
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Aqui estoy invocando el primer constructor con la clase scanner para introducir datos mediante teclado
        clase1 clase1=new clase1();
//ACA ME MARCA ERROR estoy invocando al constructor de la clase 2 (subclase) y no al de la clase1 (superclase) como lo hice en la ocacion anterior
        clase2 clase2=new clase2(int Nummanos,int Numpies,int Numojos,int Numpiernas,int Numdedos);



    }
}
class clase1{
    //5 atributos atributos,desde teclado
        int Nummanos,Numpies,Numojos,Numpiernas,Numdedos;

    //utilizando un constructor y los mostrara.
            public clase1() {
            Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Digite el numero de manos: ");
            int Nummanos=entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Digite el numero de pies: ");
            int Numpies=entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Digite el numero de ojos: ");
            int Numojos=entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Digite el numero de piernas: ");
            int Numpiernas=entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Digite el numero de dedos: ");
            int Numdedos=entrada.nextInt();
            }

            public clase1(int Nummanos,int Numpies,int Numojos,int Numpiernas,int Numdedos){
                this.Nummanos=Nummanos;
                this.Numpies=Numpies;
                this.Numojos=Numojos;
                this.Numpiernas=Numpiernas;
                this.Numdedos=Numdedos;
            }
}
```

Clase "clase2":

```
class clase2 extends clase1{
    // 4 atributos privados
    private String ocupacion="estudiante";
    private String carrera="Ingenieria en sistemas y computacion";
    private double estatura=1.70;
    private int pesokg=70;
    //3 métodos dos serán privados y un publico que invoque a los miembros privados y los muestre
    private void datospersonales(){
        System.out.println("La ocupacion es " + ocupacion + " y la carrera es " + carrera);
    }
    private void datosfisicos(){
        System.out.println("La estatura es " + estatura + " y el peso en kg es " + pesokg);
    }
    public void getdatos(){
        datospersonales();
        datosfisicos();
    }
    //Ademas  esta clase tendrá acceso al  constructor de la superclase
    public clase2(int Nummanos,int Numpies,int Numojos,int Numpiernas,int Numdedos){
        super(Nummanos,Numpies,Numojos,Numpiernas,Numdedos);
    }
}
```

Clase "clase3":

```
class clase3{
    // tendrá un método y un constructor que usted va a sobrecargar las veces que desee esos métodos serán públicos o privados
    //constructor sobrecargado
    public clase3(){
    }
    String mensaje;
    public clase3(String mensaje){
    }
    //metodo
    public void metodo() {
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes con la línea:

```
clase2 clase2=new clase2(int Nummanos,int Numpies,int Numojos,int Numpiernas,int Numdedos);
```

se debe a que no estás pasando valores como argumentos. El constructor de `clase2` está esperando valores de tipo enteros.

**Ejemplo:**

```
// Correcto
clase2 clase2 = new clase2(1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Si deseas instanciar clase2 sin pasarle nada, deberás tener un constructor vacío en `clase2`, ejemplo, en `clase2`:

```
// Constructor vacío para permitir la instancia de esta clase
    public clase2() {
    }
```

Luego, en `claseprincipal`:

```
clase2 clase2 = new clase2();
```

Tú decides cuál elegir. Ahora, deberás de buscar la forma de imprimir los datos que tiene `clase1`. Te sugiero usar `Getters`, si es que te lo permiten.

**Nota:** en este constructor de `clase1` no estás imprimiendo nada. Lo único que hace es recibir valores para luego asignarlos a las variables de la clase.

```
// Esto no imprime nada
public clase1(int Nummanos,int Numpies,int Numojos,int Numpiernas,int Numdedos){
                this.Nummanos=Nummanos;
                this.Numpies=Numpies;
                this.Numojos=Numojos;
                this.Numpiernas=Numpiernas;
                this.Numdedos=Numdedos;
            }
```

Comment: Pero tu no has mencionado nada que no supiera,la pregunta es: dado que en la superclase tengo 2 constructores,1 para invocar  ala clase escanner y otro para mostrar e imprimir los datos introducidos en el metodo anterior,entonces por que si ya lo instancie ambos constructores en la clase principal solo funciona el que me pide los datos y no el que los muestra?

Comment: @david el problema está en que en `clase1`, el segundo constructor que tu dices que "debe mostrar e imprimir los datos introducidos en el método anterior" no va a hacerlo. En este constructor no tienes ningún código para imprimir datos. Este constructor está esperando valores para luego asignarlos a las variables de la clase. Cómo va a imprimir si no tienes código que haga eso?.

Comment: @david Leyendo más detenidamente el ejercicio, el #1 dice que "estos los ingresara desde teclado utilizando un constructor y los mostrara" entonces, quiere decir que hará ambas cosas desde el mismo constructor o no?. Si es así, por qué creas un segundo constructor para imprimir los datos?. Otra cosa, el #2 dice que "tendrá acceso al constructor de la superclase" pero, cuando en `clase2` heredas de `clase1` no estás heredando nada ahora mismo entonces, por qué heredas de `clase1`? con qué fin?. Encuentro los mandatos ambiguos. Te sugiero que corrobores con algún compañero.

Comment: @david Otra cosa más, en `clase1` tienes un problema. Se supone que ya declaraste las variables arriba entonces, por qué declaras las variables nuevamente en el constructor?. Ahora mismo lo que estás haciendo es tener 10 variables diferentes, 5 globales y 5 locales para este constructor, aunque se llamen iguales. Recuerda algo, el "scope" de una variable. Si no tienes claro lo que es, te recomiendo Googlear un poco sobre esto.